# NHibernate flush/save/update does not persist

Tags: c#, nhibernate

When I try to update an entity, no matter what I do, it will not update. I've tried calling `ISession.SaveOrUpdate()`, `ISession.Merge()`, `ISession.Flush()`, etc. The session shows that the object is updated, but manually querying the database shows that the updates were not persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the `hbm.xml` format, double check that your `.hbm.xml` file does not contain `mutable="false"` in the `<class>` declaration. If it is there, then you can persist your object to the database, but any updates will opaquely fail.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me, fortunately, changing the mutable settings fix it from:

```
Mutable(false);
```

I just removed it:

```
//Mutable(false);
```